# How to web scrape multiple info from same class and attribute in Beautiful Soup without hard coded indexing of find_all function in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have web scraped few of the ratios of Mutual Funds with `BeautifulSoup` by hard coding the index only to  realize that I have misplaced some of them. The hard coding works where all of the five ratios exist but not where only some does.
[The website I'm web scraping](https://www.moneycontrol.com/mutual-funds/nav/kotak-india-growth-fund-series-iv-direct-plan-growth/MKM1087).

Case1: which has all 5 ratios
[image]

Case2: which doesn't have all 5
[image]

The code I have tried:

```
try:
    std_dev.append(bs1.find_all('div', attrs = {'class' : 'percentage'})[0].text.strip())
except:
    std_dev.append('N/A')
try:
    beta.append(bs1.find_all('div', attrs = {'class' : 'percentage'})[1].text.strip())
except:
    beta.append('N/A')
try:
    sharpe_ratio.append(bs1.find_all('div', attrs = {'class' : 'percentage'})[2].text.strip())
except:
    sharpe_ratio.append('N/A')
try:    
    treynors_ratio.append(bs1.find_all('div', attrs = {'class' : 'percentage'})[3].text.strip())
except:
    treynors_ratio.append('N/A')
try:
    jenisons_alpha.append(bs1.find_all('div', attrs = {'class' : 'percentage'})[4].text.strip())
except:
    jenisons_alpha.append('N/A')
```

This has resulted in for e.g. like 'Jenison's Alpha' value being in 'Sharpe Ratio' column in the scraped data.

Comment: Don't post screenshots... Post all your code and examples as text.

Comment: What URL is the second image is from? I don't see it on the page you have provided.

Comment: URL for the second image: https://www.moneycontrol.com/mutual-funds/nav/iti-overnight-fund-direct-plan-growth/MIT031

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should allow you to extract the required information from the page. You can then assign it to lists, etc.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url = "https://www.moneycontrol.com/mutual-funds/nav/kotak-india-growth-fund-series-iv-direct-plan-growth/MKM1087"
req = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(req.text,'lxml')

titles = [title.find(text=True, recursive=False) for title in soup.select('ul.risk_ratios h3.list')]
targets = soup.select('ul.risk_ratios div.block div.percentage')
percentages = [target.select_one('span').text for target in targets]
for t,p in zip(titles,percentages):
    print(t,p)
```

output:

```
Standard Deviation 20.26
Beta 0.77
Sharpe Ratio 0.36
Treynor's Ratio 0.09
Jension's Alpha 2.64
```